# TS: object type where every possible value must be taken

Tags: typescript, mapping, keyof

Given

```ts
const domain: string[] = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

how can I declare an object type with keys from `domain` and values covering *whole* `domain`?

Some examples for clarification:

```ts
const obj1 = {    //     correct type: values { "B", "C", "A" } of obj1 are all the values of domain
    A: "B",
    B: "C",
    C: "A",
};
```

```ts
const obj2 = {    // NOT correct type: values { "B", "C" } of obj2 are missing "A" from domain
    A: "B",
    B: "C",
    C: "B",
};
```

In other words, my object needs to be an *onto/surjective map*.

Comment: There is no specific type which meets your needs and scales well.  How many elements are going to be in your domain?  If it's less than about 7 you can exhaustively enumerate the possibilities like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjXd1m).  If it's more than about 6 then you would need to write a generic constraint like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7K5w). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I'm looking for a generic approach, because my domain may contain more than 6 elements. I would be glad if you could elaborate on your generic constraint...

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific type that is both scalable and meets your requirements.  For the example as given, you could generate a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the acceptable permutations, which would be equivalent to:

```
type Acceptable =
    { A: "A", B: "B", C: "C" } |
    { A: "A", B: "C", C: "B" } |
    { A: "B", B: "A", C: "C" } |
    { A: "B", B: "C", C: "A" } |
    { A: "C", B: "A", C: "B" } |
    { A: "C", B: "B", C: "A" };

const obj1: Acceptable = { // okay
    A: "B",
    B: "C",
    C: "A",
}; 

const obj2: Acceptable = { // error!
    A: "B",
    B: "C",
    C: "B",
};
```

That's a specific type and it will work for your example.  We could write a type utility that generates that automatically but before we bother, let's consider the scalability.

For  elements in your domain, that union would have ! ( [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)) members.  Unions in TypeScript can only hold about 100,000 members at most, meaning you can't have more than *eight* elements in your domain.  The compiler starts slowing down if you are calculating large unions anyway, so even with six or seven elements you're likely to be unhappy.

So let's forget this, as it doesn't scale.

---

Without a specific type, all we can do is write a generic [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  Instead of `Acceptable`, we can write a type function `Acceptable<T>` such that `T extends Acceptable<T>` if and only if `T` would be acceptable.  Then we can write a generic helper function like `acceptable()` that returns its input, but produces an error if its input isn't acceptable.  So instead of `const obj1: Acceptable = {...}` you'd write `const obj1 = acceptable({...})` to much the same effect.

Here's one approach to writing it:

```
type NoDuplicates<T> =
    { [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], T[Exclude<keyof T, K>]> }

const noDuplicates = <D extends PropertyKey,>(d: readonly D[]) =>
    <T extends Record<D, D> & NoDuplicates<T>>(x: T) => x;
```

My type function is actually `NoDuplicates<T>`, which will take an object type `T` and [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) it to a type where any property values that overlap with other properties are removed.  It uses [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) twice; once to say "remove this key and look up the properties from every other key", and "remove any pieces of this property that in those other places".  So `NoDuplicates<{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}>` is just `{x: 1, y: 2, z: 3}`, but `NoDuplicates<{x: 1, y: 2, z: 1}>` is `{x: never, y: 2, z: never}`.

Since the key set and the value set are the same size, then eliminating duplicates is a similar operation to guaranteeing a surjection.  (There are edge cases, I'm sure; this is meant to give a flavor of how such constraints can be built... it can be tweaked or even completely refactored if use cases warrant it, but I won't digress about that further.)

Then `noDuplicates()` is a curried function that accepts a domain as an array of key-like elements.  This is actually completely ignored at runtime, but the compiler uses it to generate the `acceptable()` function:

```
const domain = ["A", "B", "C"] as const;
const acceptable = noDuplicates(domain);
/* const acceptable: <T extends 
     Record<"A" | "B" | "C", "A" | "B" | "C"> & NoDuplicates<T>
>(x: T) => T */
```

Okay, let's try it:

```
const obj1 = acceptable({
    A: "B",
    B: "C",
    C: "A",
}); // okay
/* const obj1: { A: "B"; B: "C"; C: "A"; } */

const obj2 = acceptable({
    A: "B", // error!
    B: "C",
    C: "B", // error!
});
/* const obj2: { A: never; B: "C"; C: never; }*/

const obj3 = acceptable({
    A: "B",
    B: "A",
}) // error! Property C is missing
```

The compiler is happy about `obj1` but complains about `obj2` (duplicate values) and `obj3` (missing keys).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=8#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJiAtgQwJZhgXhgbQEQCCeANDHgEIlkDCeAujMhDKJFANwBQnYyiAphAAOyYPxjlUAcwCqYVOBgBvTjDUwoATyHiCwMUKjIARgBtxmVeutKYBAFxkipco4pVqb2jAC+MAD5W1mq2Dk5UrjQebpS+AUHBoTERbs4wnlFxgcHqSWSULl7R4VkJNnZFheGkGe6lOSEVUVXuNal4vlwJrNAwIMYAVgCMjnoGRmYWyjAA9DN9ANbImmXqYa2rapF4tMSb6e171j5d1j2w-QMATKP6-IYm5ljTczD8AE7vIO8AhPvrBX2212+1qgOOXR83E4Wh0MAAciAACIAVyEplQwGQUEEAB4ACoAPiwCVsOAA0jB0DAFvxNCAAGYwfF0RwAUQAHsBTCi4PwCRS6KR8ThOdzefzafSmfjSOTCXRiVDOOcYGBkWiMViccxsLikW8OTiwHBmAAFL46d5acl04iEgAUcEc734yAQYFMmhgSJwdAAlFhCQkCYbjaaYAAlfigd5wfWkJHEgBkCI16Mx2LxRMdHMc+MDmGJHK6qtE40eU3VqIz2sETqQaDA-q4MwAVCxwL1y-cJuZHKH+Eb+CbmGVo7H44QOv58jPmiVZ3Ul7QU2ma1qsxACcHc-nC8T8TA2zNuKrLkNnj2HpMHSprACSAlgU-rLVnJwfC3ZvMQEsVu2nZsH0gwjNMj7sBIRSQe+eCQX4J5nl2FyDFcV53De5h3gkj6kK8HxfL8z6VAkYJUPhnzfH8X6th256oY4eRgPwABuHyQS+MGOMxbHvPBiEqshIEDAAzOhFa3veazJEc6jbB+X4-m8lG-DAFogFaWjpFSzCIKgEAQOgUjcEAA)

Comment: Neat! That solved it for me. Thanks for your time and your instructive answer.